# Access config vars in Heroku with .NET Core to get the database URL

Tags: postgresql, heroku, .net-core

I deployed a web app with .NET Core 2.2 to Heroku and I want to access the Config Vars to get the database URL. How can I do tha?

Currently, I hardcoded the connection string, but this is only a temporary solution.

The code currently used:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseNpgsql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("ExtPostgresConnection")));
```

Where `ExtPostgresConnection` is the hardcoded connection string to access the database form outside of Heroku.

Do I need to use [Heroku's REST API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku [config vars are exposed to your application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#accessing-config-var-values-from-code) as [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable):

> Config vars are exposed to your app's code as environment variables. For example, in Node.js you can access your app's `DATABASE_URL` config var with `process.env.DATABASE_URL`.

In C# you should be able to use [`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2) to read them, e.g.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DATABASE_URL")
```